# How to split strings sperated by comma with escapes?

Tags: string, parsing, syntax

I have a string looks like this:

(The whole code block is a string, aka, this string contains quotation marks.)

```
"he\"llo", "world\n", "fro,m"
```

> [update] Aka, the "actual" string is this:
>
> `"\"he\\\"llo\", \"world\\n\", \"fro,m\""`

I want to get an array of strings like this:

```
[ "\"he\\\"llo\"", "\"world\\n\"", "\"fro,m\"" ]
```

> [update] Comma inside quotation marks should be remained.

In my opinion, there are several ways to solve this:

- build a automata (DFA or NFA) for this syntax
- using several status flags like `inQuote`, handle judging logics with lots of `if` `else`
- write a complex but clever Regular Expression for this

Are there any general solutions to this problem? Or how should I actually do using those thinkings above?

P.S. It couldn't be better if some syntax errors like "unclosed quotation mark" can be found.

Comment: How are you processing this? What regex engine would be used? `[^,]+` would split it as you've asked

Comment: `The whole code block is a string` ... the whole code block is _not_ a string, because some of the quotes are escaped while others are not.  Please post the actual string.

Comment: @user3783243 JavaScript's (ES6). So positive lookahead assertion is available.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Sorry for the unclear expression. You can imagine that there is a pair of quotation marks surrounding the code block. So the actual string is `"\"he\\\"llo\", \"world\\n\", \"from\", \"some\\\"where\\\"\""`. This formation is too complex, so I use that expression in the question description.

Comment: @user3783243 This pattern won't work correctly if there are comma inside quotation marks.

Comment: Questions should always provide examples of what is being asked. Original question didn't have that. The `string contains quotation marks` didnt matter

Answer (score 0):

You need to first define your grammar. This is a simple grammar for your case:

```
document = *WS [string *WS *(',' *WS string *WS)]
string   = %x22 *char %x22
char     = %x20-21 / %x23-5B / escape / %x5D-10FFFF
escape   = %x5C (%x5C / %x22 / 't' / 'n' / 'r')
WS       = %x9 / %x20
```

You can read it as:

A `document` may begin/end with a white space, then may have one or more strings separated by commas. Before and after each comma there may be some white space.

A `string` is made of characters and begins and ends with double quotes Unicode/ASCII hex code `22`.

Each character (`char`), may be: 1) any non control Unicode character before the double quotes i.e. hex `20` (`space`) or hex `21` (`exclamation mark`); 2) any character after the double quotes and before the escape slash `\` (hex `5C`); 3) an escape character sequence; 4) any other Unicode character after the slash (hex `5C`).

The escape sequence (rule `escape`) begins with the escape slash `\` and is followed by another slash, or the characters `t` for `tab`, `n` for `line feed` and `r` for `carriage return`. You may add and other escapable characters if you want, as for a C++ string syntax you can see here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape .

A `white space` (`WS`) is a tab or space, you may add and `%xA` and `%xD` for `line feed` and `carriage return` respectively.

By the use of this grammar you will get this tree for your input:
[image]

The screenshort is from the Tunnel Grammar Studio online laboratory that can run ABNF grammars (as the one above), and I work on.

After you have the grammar, you may use tools to generate a parser, or you can write one yourself. If you want to do it by hand (preferable for so small and simple grammar), you may have one function per each grammar rule that reads one character and checks is it the expected one. If your input finishes when you are parsing the `string` rule, then you have an input with a started but not finished string.

Your `actual` string syntax tree will look like that:
[image]